# If $P(x \mid y)$ is high, then does this imply that $P(y \mid x)$ is also high?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $P(x \mid y)$ is high, for example, above 0.5, does it imply that $P(y \mid x)$ is also high (above $0.5$)? If yes/no, then why? What if I know that they are dependent on each other? For what type of events may this relation hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's review the conditional probability of both $P(x|y)$ and $P(y|x)$:

$$P(x|y) = \frac{P(x \cap y)}{P(y)}$$

and

$$P(y|x) = \frac{P(x \cap y)}{P(x)}$$

The common thing in both is their joint probability. So, their discrepancy depends on $P(x)$ and $P(y)$. If these two probabilities are equal or close to each other then according to formulas, the conditional probabilities are close to each other. This also depends on the degree of dependence between $x$ and $y$.

For example consider the events of $T:\text{Thunder}$ and $B:\text{Black clouds}$. They often come together and they strongly depend on each others, so approximately you may write:

$$ P(T) \approx P(B) \approx P(T \cap B)$$

Then the conditional probabilities are equal:

$$P(B | T) \approx P(T | B) \approx 1 $$

Now consider the example of $H:\text{Being hanged}$ and $D:\text{Death}$, which one is the cause of the other one but not vice versa. We can safely assume whenever one is hanged, they die, and it's the only usage of hanging. So:

$$ P(H) \approx P(D \cap H)$$
Therefore:
$$P(D | H) = \frac{P(H \cap D)}{P(H)} \approx 1$$

However, death could be due to many other reasons than being hanged and $$P(D) \gg P(D \cap H)$$

Therefore:
$$P(H | D) = \frac{P(H \cap D)}{P(D)} \approx 0$$

Answer (score 14):

I like this example:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(\text{Dead} \mid \text{Was hanged}) \qquad \text{is high}\\
\P(\text{Was hanged} \mid \text{Dead}) \qquad \text{is low}
$$
and that should answer your question.

Comment: @Ahmad see my edit, it is not about if they are dependent, but rather what is the nature of the dependence. Being dead is strictly dependent on being hanged, more than this, there is a causal relationship, otherwise, it would not be used as a form of capital punishment.

Comment: @Tim, Sure, right! Death could be due to many things. I meant when you hear one was hanged, it gives you a high probability or information that death has occurred, otherwise, it would not be used as a form of capital punishment. However, when you hear one was dead, it tells nothing of a few about whether it was hanged or not. But yes, I must use other terminolgy.

Answer (score 8):

$P(x|y)$ and $P(y|x)$ are different things and do not have to be related. Say that you have an “algorithm” that predicts the weather. It is very simple, it always predicts “it is going to rain”. So P(predicted rain|rain) = 1, in all cases it rained, it also predicted rain. On another hand, say that in your area it rains only 5% of the time, so P(rain|predicted rain) = 0.05, since only in 5% of cases when it predicted rain (always), it rained.

Think of it geometrically. Say that you are throwing stones into a box split into four quadrants while being blindfolded (i.e. at random). If I tell you that you threw the stone into the quadrant within the $x=1$ column, the conditional probability that it was $y=1$ (you're still blindfolded!), $p(y=1|x=1)=1/2$ would be the area of $y=1,x=1$ quadrant, divided by the area of the $x=1$ column. For $p(x=1|y=1)=1/2$, the calculation would be done row-wise.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
               & x=0 &  x=1 \\ 
\hline
 y=0  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 y=1  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now imagine that you expand the area of the $y=1$ row twice. The marginal $p(y=1)=2/3$ and conditional probabilities $p(y=1|x=1)=2/3$ have changed. However, if you look at the relative areas from the $x$'s point of view, the relative areas $p(x=1|y=1)=1/2$ are still the same.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
               & x=0 &  x=1 \\ 
\hline
 y=0  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 y=1\\\phantom{y=1}  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The same can be done if you expanded the area of any of the columns instead, the result would be the opposite.

If you changed the areas on both of the dimensions, both the conditional probabilities would change. Play around with it (in your head, using pen and pencil, or using a computer) and check how do the relative areas change. If you expand the row together with the column, say making $x=1$ twice as big and $y=1$ twice as big, would make both conditional probabilities equal to $2/3$.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
               & x=0 & x=1\phantom{x=1} \\ 
\hline
 y=0  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 y=1\\\phantom{y=1}  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

But you could also do the scaling in an opposite way, expand $x=0$ and $y=1$, in such case $p(x=1|y=1)=1/3$ and $p(y=1|x=1)=2/3$.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
               & x=0\phantom{x=0} & x=1 \\ 
\hline
 y=0  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 y=1\\\phantom{y=1}  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: "So P(predicted rain|rain) = 1, in all cases it predicted rain, it rained." doesn't say clearly what I think you wanted to say.

Comment: Thank you, however, they are related through the Bayes rule.

Comment: @Ahmad Bayes theorem tells you only how to calculate one from another, it tells you nothing about them being related.

Comment: @Tim, thank you, what if I know that they are dependent? I add this to my original question.

Comment: @Tim, I also answered my question. I'm just doubtful about the calculation of the first part. You may check it.

Comment: Thanks, based on your figure, I may say that in the last table, `x=1` is a small factor among factors where `y=1`, however, meanwhile `y=1` is a major factor among factors where `x=1`. So, x is very dependent on y, but y isn't much dependent on x.

Comment: @Ahmad in the example I changed the width of one of the columns by the same amount as the height of one of the rows (x2), so you cannot say that one of the dimensions is "more" or "less" dependent than another. You also seem to be using some kind of unorthodox definition of dependence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)

Comment: I must read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information more carefully, anyways, I'm trying to relate it to mutual information. By dependency I mean how much information we gain about something if we know something happened. So, I want to distinguish a situation about two things where they give high information about either side and situations where one gives high information about the other side, but the other side doesn't give that much information about the other side.

Comment: @Ahmad you seem to be asking "if both conditional probabilities are high, are they both high?"

Comment: @Tim, you may read my answer and my examples. I want to have intuition. For example thunder and black clouds, I don't know if both conditional dependences is high or it's a mutual or shared thing that is high among them. I imagine that there is a shared thing among them that is a high percentage of both. Just want to have more real examples.

Comment: @Ahmad my answer seems to be addressing this. But for yourself, try defining what exactly you mean in here by "shared thing". You seem to be making the tautological statement that if both conditional probabilities are big, they would both be big. I'm afraid I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: If both conditional probabilities are big, what can you say about joint probability? Yes, maybe I want to say that, and in extreme case when they are too big, does it mean that X and Y are the same?

Comment: Consider two overlapping circles, where the shared area is 0.9 of each. Then I guess P(x/y) = P(y/x) = 0.9.... right? In the extreme case, both circles cover each other. I say about co-occurrence... Anyways, thanks your answer was helpful, I just must sort thing out. The message is that we shouldn't confuse co-occurance with dependency

Comment: @Ahmad what does their equal shared area tell you about the both conditional probabilities? It’s same case as in my answer if you think about it.

Comment: I added one line to my question, you may want to consider. Anyways, I must myself think about these later. It seems I have confused events and random variables, correlation and dependency, mutual information and dependency, mutual dependency and one-sided dependency (if there is such a thing), dependency and conditional probability,....